# How to Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, http, xmlhttprequest

**I tried to log in with this code but it doesn't work what**

'

```
              http.open('POST', "https://s2.travian.vip/login.php", true);

             
              http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
              http.setRequestHeader('Host', 's2.travian.vip');
              http.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0');
              http.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8');
              http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                      alert("oky");
                  }
              }
              http.send("name=abccc&password=1111111&s1.x=61&s1.y=8");'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add that line before http if that makes sense: `const http = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: Yes, I know this, but the code does not work

Comment: It could be a CORS issue if you're trying to reach another host. I've tried your code and I was able to see a triggered alert message.

Comment: Try to run that in a browser with disabled CORS